# get text content from p tag

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get description text content of each block on this page

https://twitter.com/search?q=data%20mining&src=typd&vertical=default&f=users.

html for p tag looks like

```
<p class="ProfileCard-bio u-dir" dir="ltr" data-aria-label-part=""><a href="http://t.co/kwtDyFn6dC" rel="nofollow" dir="ltr" data-expanded-url="http://DataMiningBlog.com" class="twitter-timeline-link" target="_blank" title="http://DataMiningBlog.com"><span class="invisible">http://</span><span class="js-display-url">DataMiningBlog.com</span><span class="tco-ellipsis"><span class="invisible">&nbsp;</span></span></a> covers current challenges, interviews with leading actors and book reviews related to data mining, analytics and data science.</p>
```

my code:

```
productDivs = soup.findAll('div', attrs={'class' : 'ProfileCard-content'})
for div in productDivs:
   print div.find('p', attrs={'class' : 'ProfileCard-bio u-dir'}).text
```

anything wrong here? Getting exception here

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "twitter_user_scrapper.py", line 91, in getImageList
    print div.find('p', attrs={'class' : 'ProfileCard-bio u-dir'}).text
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Comment: What is the exception?

Comment: @AnandSKumar:updated the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue might be that some `div` with `class` as `ProfileCard-content` may not have a child `p` element with class - `ProfileCard-bio u-dir` , when that happens , the following returns `None` -

```
div.find('p', attrs={'class' : ['ProfileCard-bio', 'u-dir']})
```

And that is the reason you are getting the `AttributeError`. You should get the return of above and save it in a variable , and check whether its `None` or not and take the text only if its not None.

Also, you should give class as a list of all the classes , not a single string, as -

```
attrs={'class' : ['ProfileCard-bio', 'u-dir']}
```

Example -

```
productDivs = soup.findAll('div', attrs={'class' : 'ProfileCard-content'})
for div in productDivs:
   elem = div.find('p', attrs={'class' : ['ProfileCard-bio', 'u-dir']})
   if elem:
       print elem.text
```

Comment: Are you using bs3 ? BeautifulSoup3 .

Comment: Try latest - `div.find('p', attrs={'class' : ['ProfileCard-bio', 'u-dir']})`

Comment: when i print parced content it looks like this `https://Data.gov\xa0 is the central clearinghouse of the U.S. Government\u2019s open data.` do I need any encoding here?

Comment: When printing it is coming like that?

Comment: when printing it, it should be fine , try printing, that is encoding only, but when you just check `elem.text` in interpreter you get its `repr()` output .

Comment: Also can I know why the answer was unaccepted? did the answer not work for you?