# Regular expression in python to split each text between tags

Tags: python

Here is my string
`"<p>First</p><p>Second</p><p>Third</p>"`
I want to get First, Second & Third into a list. So is there any way to do this in python?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [get text content from p tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31720272/get-text-content-from-p-tag)

Comment: Not sure this is a good dupe. Uses a third-party library and the question explicitly asks for regular expressions.

Comment: @schwobaseggl while regular expressions will be good for this very specific string example, taking in count that they probably come from some html or xml source, it will not be helpful to the OP to use this on a wider scale. See [Using regular expressions to parse HTML: why not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not)

Comment: Agreed. You should not generally use regular expressions to parse html. Which is not even generally possible, as arbitrarily nestable paired features like tags are notoriously not regular, but context-sensitive.

Comment: Thank you all of you
I found a way with re.findall as @schwobaseggl answered in this question.
The thing is I am passing text editor data on form submit in django and I want each line in different element of list. But it gave me this string which I have to split

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall):

```
import re

s = "<p>First</p><p>Second</p><p>Third</p>"

re.findall(r"<p>(.*?)</p>", s)
# ['First', 'Second', 'Third']
```

The parentheses `(...)` mark a captured group (used by findall if present) and the `?` matches non-greedily so that you don't get only one match from the first opening to the last closing tag.